# How to show choice when click on input type text using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

How can I show the user's choice when they click on input type text using JavaScript?

I want to use onclick on input type text. When the user clicks, I want to show their choice.

I tried searching for a function to do that, but I did not find any.

Could you please advise me on how to do that?

Image:

[image: Screenshot]

*remark : Australia , United Kingdom and United States not from database.

Comment: are you using jQuery's autocomplete?

Comment: One way to do this could be with Chosen (https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Reinventing the wheel. :)

If you need to support ancient browsers (hope it should work for older IE versions?), for some reason, you could use pretty simple JS.

HTML&CSS setup (just for demo purposes, can be tweaked to fit your needs)

```
<div id="autocomplete">
<input type="text" autocomplete="off" id="search">
    <ul id="options">

    </ul>
    </div>
```

Notice usage of `autocomplete=off` (to prevent default browser behavior)!

Simple CSS:

```
#autocomplete {
    width:200px;
    position:relative;
    height:300px;
}

#search {
    width:200px;
    height:30px;
    border:1px solid #666;
    margin:0;

}

#options {
    margin:2px;
    padding:0;
    display:none;
    list-style-type:none;
    border:1px solid #666;
    position:absolute;
    top:30px;
    left:0px;
    width:100%;
}
#options li {
    line-height:25px;
     color:blue;
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

And pretty simple javascript:

```
countries=['Australia','United Kingdom','United States'];
input=document.getElementById('search');
options=document.getElementById('options');
for(i=0;i<countries.length;i++) {
    options.innerHTML+='<li>'+countries[i]+'</li>';


}

document.body.onclick=function(event) {
    if(event.target!=input)
      options.style.display='none';
}


input.onclick=function() {
    this.value='';
      options.style.display='block';
}


for(i=0;i<countries.length;i++) {
   options.getElementsByTagName('li')[i].onclick = function(){

       input.value= this.textContent;

    }    


}
```

So, place options in array, set variables for text and list, populate list with array values, hide list on outside click, show it on input click, replace input text with chosen list item.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/yerfemr4/2/

Answer (score 6):

you can use below code if your browser supports html5

```html
<html>
    <body>
    <label for="country_name">Country : </label><input id="country_name" name="country_name" type="text" list="country" />
    <datalist id="country">
       <option value="Australia">
       <option value="United Kingdom">
       <option value="United States">
       </datalist>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: as I already mention this will only work if your browser supports html5. since IE7 is quite old it might not be supporting html5

Answer (score 1):

You can use an html 'select' tag.

example:

```html
<select>
  <option value=""></option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

Comment: i have to use text type

Comment: soo you want the user to be able to type in the textbox?